# Disable WebP format in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

This is one of the most irritating behaviours I've ever experienced.

You retrieve a JPG file from the Web, but Chrome forces you to download it in WEBP format. Absurd conversion especially when it is not desired (and there are many, many reasons for this: wanting the exact original file, retrieving metadata, problems reusing the webp file in other software, etc).

Is there a way to disable this annoying behaviour?

example: https://www.predictiveanalyticstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Stardog.jpg

Comment: FYI, if I use [Brave](https://brave.com/) (a Chromium-based browser) to download that file, I get a JPG file and not a WEBP file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You retrieve a JPG file from the Web, but Chrome forces you to download it in WEBP format.

Don't blame Chrome for this behavior. This behavior is implemented by [the "Polish" image optimizer in CloudFlare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-polish-automatic-image-optimizati/), not by the browser.

There is no way to disable WebP support in Chrome; even if there were, it would not prevent web servers from delivering WebP images if they believe your browser would prefer them.

Comment: You are right, I can see the header `cf-polished: qual=85, origFmt=jpeg, origSize=44781 content-disposition: inline; filename="....webp"`. Quite annoying that the original final cannot be downloaded.

Comment: Well, Chrome _announces_ WebP support in its HTTP "Accept:" header, so maybe you could have an extension that modifies this header to remove image/webp?

Comment: @grawity My experience has been that Cloudflare is pretty insistent about trying to deliver WebP. Last time I tried, modifying or omitting the `Accept` header had no effect.

Comment: Oh so it means CF is doing the User-Agent nonsense then. Sigh

Answer (score 9):

Try putting a `?` after the image location, then save.

Make `http://example.com/image.png` like this `http://example.com/image.png?` and CMD+S save (Mac) will save as the expected format.

Comment: Great workaround

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: You might have to add some random text after the ? - the ? alone may not work. This random text will generally bypass CloudFlare/whoever's CDN/caching which has optimized as webp and instead download the original by sending a pull request to the origin server

Comment: Still works @ date time stamp.

Comment: This workaround doesn't always work.

Comment: This depends on how the CDN is set up to detect image types to convert. Some will detect based on the url ending .png or .jpg, which allows this trick to bypass the image conversion step. If the CDN is actually doing filetype detection (safer, but slower in a way that matters a lot at that scale) or looking at just the path rather than the URL (Slower than just the URL, faster than filetype detection) this workaround won't work. The "best" way to do it would be with something like the curl request below, which doesn't send webp in the "Accepts" header, so the CDN won't convert it.

Comment: @Aquarion, you are right.  When I answered way back, the solution was pretty universal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl` to download it from the command line:

`curl -O https://www.predictiveanalyticstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Stardog.jpg`

It's available by default in OS X, Linux, and Windows 10. If you have an older version of Windows, [you can install curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216825/450127).

You can do the same with `wget` if you prefer:

`wget https://www.predictiveanalyticstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Stardog.jpg`

Comment: Windows already has native curl since version 1803, i.e. 3 years ago. And PowerShell already has all curl's capabilities

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most versatile way is to use [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en) to change your "Accept" request header to the value "image/avif,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8".

Any sites that are still serving WebP despite the Accept request header now missing acceptance for WebP can be tricked by modifying the User-Agent header. Again, [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en) will be able to accomplish this, although that needs a bit more caution, because a lot of websites will serve entirely different content based on the User-Agent.

Comment: FYI the ModHeader extension recently became ad-injecting malware